# unsupported keySystem Exception occured according to EME Specification

Tags: html5-video

In Chrome browser (version is 51.0.2704.63), according to EME specification, when I use

```js
 navigator.requestMediaKeyAccess(keySystem, supportedConfig)
```

`unsupported keySystem` exception occured,

parameters are as follows

```js
keySystem: 'com.widevine.alpha'

supportedConfig: [{
            initDataTypes: ['keyids', 'webm'],
            audioCapabilities: [{
                contentType: 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"'
            }],
            videoCapabilities: [{
                contentType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"'
            }]
        }]
```

somebody can tell me why `unsupported keySystem` exception occured?

Answer (score 0):

Could be because chrome is "Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins"

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

So the navigator.requestMediaKeyAccess(keySystem, supportedConfig) must be used in a "secure origin" aka. https.

Answer (score 0):

this is because wide vine is either disabled or not installed .

you can verify using the url : chrome://plugins/